# Opening a folder using vba so I can paste an image, in Access 2016. I have non-working options

Tags: vba

The following code (under a button) takes me to the correct Folder. BUT! I cannot paste an image. The "Paste" option is showing but it is greyed out. Is there an alternative to "vbNormalFocus" which would open the folder in a "non-Read Only" format?

```
Dim Foldername As String
Foldername = "c:\Users\John Smith\Desktop\DBFolder\DBImagesPeople"
Shell "C:\windows\explorer.exe """ & Foldername & "", vbNormalFocus
```

Or a completely different route? This takes me so close!!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function

Comment: I don't think that your problem is that the folder is opened in read only mode. The problem is that there is nothing in the paste-buffer that you could paste, therefore the button is greyed out. You can paste only files using the explorer, not bitmaps. Where do you get your image from?

Comment: From LinkedIn or from IMDb - l hope this helps

Comment: The code is simply to open the folder. But I want it to open the folder in an "editable" format. When I "Save as..." a photo image in LinkedIn, the target folder is opened with the image name ready to save. However I cannot be sure that this folder will always be the correct one. I do not know that folder is :sekected" by Windows.

Comment: FunThomas - I have 2 buttons on my Access 2016 form. One is for LinkedIN and one is for "Add Photo". LinkedIn is a good place to find photos of business contacts, hence the button. Having found the individual, and copied the image "Save image as ...", I want the user to press the Add Photo button then go directly to the folder where the image should be pasted. This is the dialogue box I want the Add Photo button to open. I am new to this forum and do not know how to add an illustration.

Comment: FunThomas - you are right, of course!! What I did not realise is that when I do a "Save image as...", it does not save the image to the clipboard. Thus, I have to change my system. I was trying to be helpful to the user but I cannot. I will have to re-write the Guide and succumb to a limitation within Access (and I always thought that anything is possible). I will have to add in an extra stage in the process. I thank you for your time and contribution, Leon

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch:

You don't look to be copying anything in the code shown so...

```
Dim FileNumber As Integer
Dim retVal As Variant
Dim MY_FILENAME As String

'Batch Name and location
MY_FILENAME = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "File.bat"
FileNumber = FreeFile

'create batch file
Open MY_FILENAME For Output As #FileNumber
Print #FileNumber, "@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then"
Print #FileNumber, "@echo off"
Print #FileNumber, "set Path=%~dp0"
Print #FileNumber, "copy C:\Users\John C:\Users\Sandra "
Print #FileNumber, "DEL " & Chr(34) & "%~f0" & Chr(34) ' delete itself'
Print #FileNumber, "exit /b"  'exit code'

Close #FileNumber

retVal = Shell(MY_FILENAME, vbNormalFocus)
```